# Python code not executing

Tags: python, http-post

I have the following code which is executed from the command line:

```
import cgi,time,os,json,sys,zipfile,urllib2
from os import curdir, sep
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from time import strftime
from poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith("/"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write("<HTML> GET OK.<BR>")
                return  
            return

        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)


    def do_POST(self):
        global rootnode
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
        if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
            query=cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type',    'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        file = query.get('file')

        zfile = "C:\Users\VM1\Desktop\data.zip"
        extract_path = "C:\Users\VM1\Desktop\data\\"

        f = open(zfile, "wb")
        f.write(file[0])
        f.close()
        self.wfile.write("POST OK. File received from VM Host")
        print("File received from VM Host.")
        print("Unzipping zip file")
        unzip = zipfile.ZipFile(zfile)
        unzip.extractall(extract_path)
        print "Files extracted to " + extract_path
        scan_path = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\AVG2012\\avgscana.exe" /repok /report=C:\Users\VM1\Desktop\\avg_scan_results.txt /scan=' + extract_path
        os.system('"%s"' % scan_path)
        self.write_json_report()
        self.upload_json_report()
        return

    def write_json_report(self):
        scan_results = open("avg_scan_results.txt", "r")
        saved = sys.stdout
        f = file('avg_report.json', 'wb')
        sys.stdout = f
        dict2 = {}
        for line in scan_results:
            if ".jpg" in line:
                result = line.split('\\')
                result_split = result[5].split(' ')
                filename = result_split[0]
                raw_status = result_split[3]
                if "OK" in raw_status:
                    status = "Okay"
                    status_code = "0"
                elif "Virus identified" in raw_status:
                    status = raw_status
                    status_code = "1"
                dict2[filename] = {'FileName': filename, 'DateTime': strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'statusCode': status_code, 'Description': status}
        print json.dumps(dict2)
        sys.stdout = saved
        f.close()
        print ""
        print "JSON report written"
        json_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("avg_report.zip", "w")
        try:
            json_zip.write('avg_report.json')
        finally:
            json_zip.close()
        return

    def upload_json_report(self):
        av_name = "AVG Free 2012"
        av_version = ""
        scan_results = open("avg_scan_results.txt", "r")
        for line in scan_results:
            if "Program version" in line:
                version_split = line.split(', ')
                program_version_full = version_split[0]
                program_version_split = program_version_full.split(' ')
                av_version = program_version_split[2]
        register_openers()
        datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"av_name": av_name, "av_version": av_version, "filename": "avg_report.zip", "content": open("avg_report.zip", "rb")})
        request = urllib2.Request("http://" + self.client_address[0] + ":8080/", datagen, headers)
        print "Uploading JSON report"
        print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
        return

def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHandler)
        print 'Server started..'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'KeyboardInterrupt received, shutting down server'
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The rest of the functions worked fine except for `upload_json_report()`. The string `Uploading JSON report` shows but the line after doesn't execute. My server which is listening for the request does not receive anything. Is there anything wrong with the code here? If yes, what is the problem and how do I solve it? Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I have created a seperate client with the following lines from the method:

```
register_openers()
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"av_name": av_name, "av_version": av_version, "filename": "avg_report.zip", "content": open("avg_report.zip", "rb")})
request = urllib2.Request("http://" + self.client_address[0] + ":8080/", datagen, headers)
print "Uploading JSON report"
print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

This worked. I'm confused as to why the same lines of codes could not work in the function.

Comment: are you sure urllib2 is working? try this on python interpretter  and see if it's working. 
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")

Comment: My urllib2 is definitely working because i copied and paste the codes from `register_openers()` onwards and it worked

Comment: The posted code is not valid Python (for example, see the indentation at lines 12-18). I don't want to change it because I'm not sure what the original is, and it changes the meaning

Comment: That was my formatting error, I have edited it

Comment: Great- but there's still one error (the indented second return line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseHTTPRequestHandler` maintains a single-threaded (and single-process) server. This means that each request has to finish executing before another request can be executed.

The `upload_json_report` function is called from within the `do_POST` method. While it is running, your server can't handle anything else. But then at the line:

```
    print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

You are actually trying to upload the .zip file *to the same port, 8080.* Thus, `upload_json_report` is waiting for `do_POST` to finish, and `do_POST` is waiting for `upload_json_report` to finish, so of course they will never stop waiting.

Incidentally, this explains why it was working on your server (I assume it was multithreaded, though you'd need to provide more details), *and* why it works when you perform it using a separate client (it's not waiting for itself to finish).

Comment: I see.. I have a server which is running using the same structure as this one. Is there any ways to make it multi-thread?

Comment: For one thing, I'm not exactly sure why you are effectively having this server upload the file to itself. Or is it sending it to the client?

Comment: This code lays in a VM, which will upload the file to the VM host server after receiving a file from a client.

Comment: The VM is on a different machine than the host server? The question is whether they would both end up using port 8080. Also, why not use an existing server such as apache with mod_python?

Comment: The VM is on the same machine as the host server. I used this above code is because I wanted a lightweight solution. But I will try it out on Apache with mod_python and see how it goes. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Absolutely. You should also look into existing web frameworks such as Django or Pylons that could streamline how you work with the server. There's a lot that can be said on this topic

Comment: you can make the server multithreaded with the SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn mix-in

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to debug the code. To do that, I'd remove the `print` statements, add `pdb.set_trace` just before the `urllib2.urlopen` method call and run the script. Once the debugger takes over, I'd check that the url is the one that you expect, try to execute the next line and check that what's the value returned by `urllib2.urlopen` (response code, text, etc). That should provide you enough information about what's going on and hopefully let you know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try it out and give you guys an update on it

Comment: How do you check for the url? I've tried and could not get any printout of the url

Comment: @androidnoob In the debugger, `p request.get_full_url()` should print the url that was generated.

Comment: It only prints out the ip address of my server, no variables, I guess it is not POST encoded. But strange, it worked on my server but not this one..

Answer (score 0):

`urllib2.urlopen(...)` returns a file descriptor object which which you must read to print out the response. Essentially in order to see what response its getting from the server you need to do `print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()`

Comment: I've tried that, but the code is still not executing, nor my server is receiving any POST requests

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add "try" "except" around the "urllib2.urlopen" line, to see if any exception was raised.

```
try:
    request = urllib2.Request("http://" + self.client_address[0] + ":8080/", datagen, headers)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

with the printed exception information, you might have some clues.